# How to cache assets in a Windows Web View when loaded from a Stream Resolver

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm building a Windows Store App using C# / XAML that targets Windows 8.1.  The app allows for offline viewing of html files.  These (offline) files are downloaded and stored in the LocalData directory after the user signs in.

I'm using a `IUriToStreamResolver` to load the files. The problem I'm having is that the `WebView` doesn't seem to cache assets (css, javascript, fonts) when a file is loaded from a `StreamResolver` (my resolver gets hit on every page for every resource).  This results in a flash of unstyled text which does not occur when viewing the same exact html / css online.  Is there any way to get a `Webview` to cache assets when the file is loaded from a stream resolver?

I've tried using `ms-local-stream://appname_KEY/folder/file` and `ms-appdata:///local` in my html but this doesn't work (files are not loaded) - although I believe the schemes do work from the C# side (i.e. when creating a new url object).

Comment: Have you tried using the new x-ms-webview : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn301831.aspx

Comment: x-ms-webview isn't for XAML apps.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is caching, and not something else?  You can test this out by running ProcMon during the load and checking to see if there's a disk read.  If there is a disk read, that means that the URI generated for the object is different every time you load the page.  Perhaps you can have a static URI resolver in the App.XAML.cs page and refer to it whenever you need to load it.